# Setup Debian mirrors DURING installation

Tags: debian-installer

I have to install wheezy on old hardware, because all new versions starting with Jessie won't run on it. I used netinstall image, but have a problem during installation because all debian mirrors do not contain "dists/wheezy" any more (debug console shows the wget request to fetch the Release file). I would try to redirect the installer to "http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/", but cannot find the place/file where all the mirrors are saved to modify it.

So how can I tell the installer to look for the wheezy files elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I should read the list of options carefully...
The very first option is the possibility to enter the repo url manually